# Using screen.onclick() in Turtle with a function that returns multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to use the coordinates from a user's mouse click as the x and y for another function. When that second function runs, it returns two values (not x and y).

But when I run the onclick method, I get "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" before I even click anything.

```
def on_click(x, y):
        t = turtle.Turtle()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, y)

        #do stuff part 1
        #do stuff part 2

        return value1, value2

def main():
        t = turtle.Turtle()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        value1, value2 = screen.onclick(on_click)

        #do other stuff with value1 and value2

main()
```

Am I using the turtle onclick function incorrectly? Or perhaps setting up my turtle screen wrong?

Else, if I can't return multiple values while using onclick, what would be a work around for getting those two values back into my main function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This syntax indicates you are nor thinking about event handlers correctly:

```
value1, value2 = screen.onclick(on_click)
```

The `screen.onclick()` function *doesn't* return anything (i.e. `None`) and your `on_click()` function *can't* return anything (i.e. `None`).  You are not calling `on_click()` at this point in the code, it will be called in the future if/when a click occurs, so returning values doesn't apply.  (The caller can't use them.)

You've got some choices: you can put `(value1, value2)` into a *global* for some other code to access; you can pass it to another function call.  But you can't *return* it.  Structurally, your code might look like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def on_click(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    # do stuff part 1
    # do stuff part 2

    some_other_function(value1, value2)

    screen.onclick(on_click)  # reenable handler

def some_other_function(v1, v2):
    #  do other stuff with value1 and value2
    pass

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()

screen.onclick(on_click)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I understand now why expecting a return from onclick() was incorrect. 

I'm still a little confused about how to just get the x, y coordinates from a click to be used elsewhere. 

To simplify my question: would it be possible to use onclick() to call another function which just returns the x and y as values?

Comment: @kalme, ask yourself, "returns the x and y to where?".  Returning the values to the `onclick()` handler does no good.  Only functions *you* call can return values to *you*.  Functions that are called by someone else on your behalf need to be handled differently.  The key is to make sure that the `onclick()` handler function has access to enough program state to do something useful with the x and y values.  E.g. if were a method of an object instance, rather than a global function, it would have more information to work with.